# STM32F4 output on PD15 creating an unwanted PWM signal on PD9

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32f4

```
        #include "stm32f4xx.h"
        #include "stm32f4xx_hal_def.h"
        #include "stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.h"
        #include "stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.h"

        int main(void) {
        uint32_t  S1S2, S11S12,S21S22,S31S32,S41S42,S51S52,S61S62;
        uint32_t  comp1,notComp1, comp2,notComp2,comp3,notComp3,inj,notInj,ssgn,notSsgn;

          //Define the structure
         GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

//Start the clock on port D
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;

//Configure the GPIOD OUTPUT pin registers
// port D OUTPUT PIN
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin =
        GPIO_PIN_15  //s1 s2
        | GPIO_PIN_14 //s61 s62
        |GPIO_PIN_13 //s51 s52
        |GPIO_PIN_12  //s41 s42
        |GPIO_PIN_11 //s31 s32
        |GPIO_PIN_10 //s21 s22
        |GPIO_PIN_9; //s11 s12
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;

    //Configure the GPIOD INPUT pin registers
    // Port A INPUT PINs
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin =
GPIO_PIN_15   //COMP 1
|GPIO_PIN_14  //COMP 2
|GPIO_PIN_13; //COMP 3
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN;

    //Configure the GPIOD INPUT pin registers
    // port B INPUT PIN
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin =
GPIO_PIN_15 //Ssgn
|GPIO_PIN_14  //Sinj
|GPIO_PIN_13; //Sinj-
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

while (1)
    {
                notInj = ~GPIOB->IDR&GPIO_PIN_14;
                notInj = notInj << 1;
                comp1 = GPIOA->IDR&GPIO_PIN_15;
                notComp1 = ~GPIOA->IDR&GPIO_PIN_15;
                ssgn = GPIOB->IDR&GPIO_PIN_15;
                notSsgn = ~GPIOB->IDR&GPIO_PIN_15;
                comp3 = GPIOA->IDR&GPIO_PIN_13;
                comp3 = comp3 << 2;
                notComp3 = ~GPIOA->IDR&GPIO_PIN_13;
                notComp3 = notComp3 << 2;
                inj =  GPIOB->IDR&GPIO_PIN_14;
                inj = inj << 1;
                comp2 = GPIOA->IDR&GPIO_PIN_14;
                comp2 = comp2 << 1;
                notComp2 = ~GPIOA->IDR&GPIO_PIN_14;
                notComp2 = notComp2 << 1;

 ///////////////S1S2//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        S1S2 = notInj;
        GPIOD->ODR = S1S2; //output is now on pin 15
  /////////////////////S11S12////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        S11S12 = ((comp1&notComp3)&(ssgn&inj)) | ((notComp1&comp3)&(notSsgn&inj));
        S11S12 = S11S12 >> 6;
        GPIOD->ODR = S11S12; //output on pin 9
   }
}
```

When i flash this code to the board and connect the oscilloscope to Pin 9 i get a PWM signal when i should be getting a straight line for DC voltage if i however comment out  //GPIOD->ODR = S1S2 i get a straight line in the oscilloscope as i should.

inputs PA15 HIGH, PB15 HIGH and PA13 HIGH everything else low.

If anyone understands what im doing wrong id appreciate an answer thanks in advance.

should be getting a straight line not this.
[http://imgur.com/gallery/YBWom](https://imgur.com/gallery/YBWom)

Comment: Can you give us a complete code example?

Comment: sure thing in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because an assignment like `GPIOD->ODR = value` sets all 16 port bits at once, so each assignment resets the port bit that the other one has just set.

You can calculate all output pin values, and set them at once

```
S1S2 = notInj;
// will do later : GPIOD->ODR = S1S2; //output is now on pin 15
S11S12 = ((comp1&notComp3)&(ssgn&inj)) | ((notComp1&comp3)&(notSsgn&inj));
S11S12 = S11S12 >> 6;
GPIOD->ODR = S11S12 | S1S2; //output on pin 9 AND 15
```

or you can mask the port bit values

```
GPIOD->ODR = (GPIOD->ODR & ~GPIO_PIN_15) | S1S2;
// ...
GPIOD->ODR = (GPIOD->ODR & ~GPIO_PIN_9) | S11S12;
```

or use the BSRR register to change individual port bits

```
GPIOD->BSRR = S1S2 ? (1 << 15) : (1 << (15 + 16));
// ...
GPIOD->BSRR = S11S12 ? (1 << 9) : (1 << (9 + 16));
```

or figure out the Bit-Banding address of the port bits, and set them directly

```
#define GPIOD_ODR_OFFSET ((uint32_t)&(GPIOD->ODR) - (PERIPH_BASE))
#define GPIOD_ODR_BB (PERIPH_BB_BASE + GPIOD_ODR_OFFSET * 32U)
#define GPIOD_ODR_PIN(x) ((volatile uint32_t *)(GPIO_ODR_BB + (x) * 4))
// calculate S1S2 ...
GPIOD_ODR_PIN(15) = S1S2;
// calculate S11S12 ...
GPIOD_ODR_PIN(9) = S11S12;
```

Comment: Yeah  figured this out moments later after posting this... hahaha thank you for the very detailed answer i really appreciate it